# Kerberos ticket validity

Tags: kerberos

I have a Windows client which is joined to a Active Directory Server.
I login using a domain user id and password. On login I get a Kerberos ticket which has lifetime of 10hrs.

I am connected to the Windows client using MS Remote Desktop. What I observed is, when I disconnect on RDP and then reconnect, I see that whatever apps or terminals I had opened are still open, which means, it was just a disconnect and not a sing-out.  But when I do a klist, I see that ticket validity is extended to 10hrs from my re-connect time. Just trying to understand why the ticket life is reset on re-connect. I'm not facing issue, just trying to understand this observation. Is that how it is intended to work ? Thanks for any info.

I was under the impression that only sign-out and sign-in will get a new Kerberos ticket.

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Kerberos tickets can be *renewable,* i.e. just like you can use the TGT ticket to get service tickets, you can also use the current TGT to get a *fresh TGT* with another 10-hour lifetime. Windows will automatically keep renewing your krbtgt ticket for as long as possible (usually 7 days total).
2. Sign-in is not the only time you get a ticket; that can also happen when you lock and unlock the session, as you provide the password when unlocking. For example, if your session lasts long enough that the TGT expires for good (i.e. reaches its "max renew time"), I believe Windows will ask you to lock/unlock for a new ticket without requiring you to fully log off.
3. Unlike other Kerberos-using protocols (which only send a ticket), RDP deliberately sends your real password to the Remote Desktop server so that the server could treat the connection as a full login – or session unlock – and get you a new ticket if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ticket renewal request and new ticket request are different operations.

Pls see below the endtime and renew-till fields of a ticket:
Ref: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4120.txt

"endtime
This field contains the time after which the ticket will not be
honored (its expiration time).  Note that individual services MAY
place their own limits on the life of a ticket and MAY reject
tickets which have not yet expired.  As such, this is really an
upper bound on the expiration time for the ticket.

renew-till
This field is only present in tickets that have the RENEWABLE flag
set in the flags field.  It indicates the maximum endtime that may
be included in a renewal.  It can be thought of as the absolute
expiration time for the ticket, including all renewals."

For example : In Windows endtime is governed by 'Maximum lifetime for user ticket" policy and renew-till field is governed by 'Maximum lifetime for user ticket renewal' for which default values are 10 hrs and 7 days respectively.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-10/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/kerberos-policy

In your case, the same ticket might have been renewed when you reconnect to the remote server, you may verify via Security Event Logs on the Domain Controller (Event ID:4770)

Pls note that TGT are TGS are different types of Kerberos tickets, and you should see the tickets' expiry, renewal,flags etc using klist.

When the user logs off as you point out, all tickets are purged which were used during logged-on time

Comment: TGS is not a type of Kerberos ticket at all – "Ticket-granting service" is a function of the KDC.

Comment: Ref: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4120.txt 7.3.  Name of the TGS
   The principal identifier of the ticket-granting service shall be
   composed of three parts: the realm of the KDC issuing the TGS ticket,
   and a two-part name of type NT-SRV-INST, with the first part "krbtgt"
   and the second part the name of the realm that will accept the TGT.

Comment: Yeah, so if you read that carefully, it's talking about the TGT, meaning TGS is _not_ a different type of Kerberos ticket; at most, it would be the exact same type as TGT. (Really though, "the TGS ticket" is to be read as "the ticket for the TGS", which is what the TGT is.)

Comment: So the RFC meant to say TGT but they said TGS Ticket instead.?.. I do not think this term discussion is in the scope of this post. For me it TGT is a ticket to the funfair entrance, and TGS Ticket is a ticket to the Carousel which you can buy only with funfair entrance ticket.